# Scraping only after data loads

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is a bot to download mp4 files. The code is not entering the 2nd if statement, so it could be possible that the soup.find_all('a') cannot find the link, how do I fix this?

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

domain=Request("http://online-courses.club/baugasm-series-8-design-abstract-textures-and-poster-with-acrylic-paint-photoshop-and-cinema-4d/")
domain.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
response =urlopen(domain)
html = response.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
c=1
print("url opened")
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    c=c+1
    url=link.get('href')
    if("http://mediafile.cloud/" in url):
        domain2 = Request(url)
        domain2.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
        response2=urlopen(domain2)
        print("url2 opened")
        time.sleep(61)
        html2=response2.read()
        soup2=BeautifulSoup(html2,"html.parser")
        for link2 in soup2.find_all('a'):
            url2=link2.get('href')
            if("http://mediafile.cloud/" in url2):
                domain3 = Request(url2)
                domain3.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
                response3=urlopen(domain3)
                html3 = response3.read()
                print(html3)
            break
```

Note that for this particular website the 1st for loop will encounter multiple links and the second will encounter 1 download link only. This link has a time delay of 60 seconds, I need the data after the delay, the above program is giving the data of the page before the delay.
Also to run the code you will need to add your user agent in place of 'Mozilla/5.0' in the code snippets :`domain3.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')`

Comment: Looking at your code it's not very clear what are you trying to do. What information do you want to get?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Open the link in domain request, in that you will see many links to download mp4 files but you have to open all the links individually and there is a time delay of 60 seconds to avoid that I am using the above program but it cannot fetch the final link. Just visit the webpage you'll understand

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to download the mp4 from `http://mediafile.cloud/` and you don't know how.

Comment: @AndrejKesely that is not the complete link, the complete link is mentioned in the code and yes you could say that

Comment: @AndrejKesely can you please take a look at the updated question

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the page source of a `mediafile.cloud` site (http://mediafile.cloud/fa407a20649c654b) and found out that the link to download is created by a JS code:

```
    var milisec = 0;
    var seconds = 60;

    function display()
    {
        $('.btn-free').hide();
        $('.download-timer').show();
        if (seconds == 0)
        {
            $('.download-timer').html("<a class='btn btn-default' href='http://mediafile.cloud/fa407a20649c654b?pt=WTBsdlFVMHdXbkZzT0RGMmRURnBORVpFZDBaVmR6MDlPcWQ3TzBtN0dsRC93M2ZpY3VVV2VwUT0%3D'>download/view now</a>");
        }
        else
        {
            $('.download-timer-seconds').html(seconds);
        }
        seconds--;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.download-timer-seconds').html(60);
        countdownTimer = setInterval('display()', 1000);
    });
```

So if you have to read text from `<script>` tag that contains `http://mediafile.cloud/`, which will give you all the code above, then you have to find a way to extract the link from it.

Comment: X any idea on how to extract the link?

Comment: Say `jscode` is what you read from the `<script>` tag: 
`link = jscode[jscode.find("http://mediafile.cloud/"):jscode.find("\'>download/view now</a>")]`

Comment: @Sbsndj Remember to find the right `<script>` tag first. (2nd tag in this case)